# How to change label width for inputfield in VF page

Tags: visualforce, css, label

I have VF page designed as a form with multiple fields (input, output, radio button) as shown below. I would like to extend the label on my form to represent 30% of the space. At the moment it is all stuck on the left hand side. I am already using CSS style but could not figure it out how to fix the label width. 
Any idea?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Sylvie

[image: Example]

I have tried the table solution but it is not what I want to achieve. I would like the label to extend and moreover my radio button labels have disappeared. See below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @ultima67 Please share the code snippet.

Comment: try putting !important to each line...it works for me

"color: red !important;"

Comment: When I add a style to my apex:inputfield such as style="width: 30% ! important", it change the size of the input field not the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by creating a style for the label and for the radio button:

```
 label {
      float: left;
      width: 150px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      text-align: left;
   }
 .radioB input, .radioB label{
      float:none;
      display:inline;
      width: 30px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use table for formatting and use below code.

```
 table td {
        width: 30%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

---

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>forth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>this is really long</td><td>third</td><td>forth</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```